Following a Solana token guide and found out later on the info is dated. Not I'm getting an error when I try to check my spl-token accounts
I was following the https://mafyuh.com/posts/spl-token-cli/ guide, and used this command "as instructed"
PS C:\Users\Keola> solana config set --url https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com  --keypair 14fbryUnN5Px4GGg1MMgTKawpyvBXUzk4p8JGbtMfNud
Config File: C:\Users\Keola\.config\solana\cli\config.yml
RPC URL: https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com
WebSocket URL: wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/ (computed)
Keypair Path: 14fbryUnN5Px4GGg1MMgTKawpyvBXUzk4p8JGbtMfNud

Commitment: confirmed now, however, I found out that Solana has changed the way you add metadata data AGAIN, so I'm not even sure if I can get this to work anymore.. So, I went to a command and got a weird error and now even trying to check accounts i get this error;
PS C:\Users\Keola> spl-token accounts
Error: "default signer is required, please specify a valid default signer by identifying a valid configuration file using the --config argument, or by creating a valid config at the default location of ~/.config/solana/cli/config.yml using the solana config command"
PS C:\Users\Keola>

How do I fix this? What command do I use? Do I recover the account or something? I'm trying to do something SO simple in my opinion, yet Solana is changing the way it's done almost MONTHLY and making it more and more complicated and annoying every time. I don't want to have to remint a 6th time cause now Solana expects you do add --enable-metadata DURING the mint.
I have gotten virtual 0 progress done and yet I've had to write 3 questions on here for things that are in my opinion, stupid design choices by Solana, "solana uses u64 so you cant make a token big if you have lots of decimals to future proof your economy" ->reminted, how do us use arweave ; "you don't add metadata that way anymore" -> remint?! This is getting out of hand man and I really hope if your a Solana dev you read this cause I swear man any guy who's not looking to make a 10 minute scam coin is going to not touch your blockchain if you keep making updates like toddlers that just make the process of updating MORE convoluted. So for the LOVE OF GOD, someone help me cause i'm || close to use ETH, ETH is more expensive but literally 100x easier than this BS.
P.S. Sorry I'm so mad but understand, I been trying to make a coin I have authority over since march 30th. Everytime I get close to being able to get a token ready, it's problem after problem after problem cause one thing that isn't said in big red warning breaks the entire f&*^ing coin like I'm looking at info and to actually absorb what seems like a million pages of docs where, literally 2/3 of them are "archived and discontinued" I'm trying to learn in doable chunks to not melt my brain and confuse myself and it's STILL happening. I do not understand why github forking was removed. Solana makes money, hire a live admin to sort through the requests. problem solved that method was literally so easy anyone could do it, then you said "nah lets just make this harder, and now lets change it again and make it where if you use the old methods you actually f$%^ up your coin. I can't help but me mad. sorry.

solana config get and then updated to the correct keypair using solana config set however, now there is a new issue I gotta change.. great. lmao
